# What other vegetables can be used in cake/muffin baking?

Tags: baking, vegetables, muffins

Vegetables have been commonly used in baking cakes and muffins. A common one is carrots to make one of my fave - carrot cake. Recently I also found out about adding zucchinis (or courgettes) to brownies and cakes. I also found some recipes advising using beetroot in chocolate cakes.

I am wondering what other vegetables can be used in baking? Is there anything I should watch out for? Does a certain vegetable pair well with another ingredient?

Comment: How do you define "baking"? If you don't insist on sweet results, you can bake practically any vegetable, especially as a filling in a strudel or lasagna. A savoury muffin can also contain practically any plant you can cut small enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, you missed the obvious: pumpkin!

This is biologically a fruit, actually, as is the zucchini.
Pumpkin loves same spices as carrot. Maybe even rum or butterscotch too.

Now, beetroot *is* a veg and colors cakes delectably; perhaps why it was originally added when going stingy on the cocoa.

How about parsnip next? Sweet and nutty, I think pistachios would complement it well in a recipe borrowed from zucchini bread.

more veg here:
http://www.deliciousmagazine.co.uk/articles/how-to-make-cakes-from-vegetables

p.s. if you haven't guessed Rabarber is rhubarb

Answer (score 2):

[Potato bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_bread) is a staple in many cultures, and [potatoes can be baked in sweet cakes](http://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/chocolate-potato-cake-3) as well.

And don't forget cornbread!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is done all over the world, but here (austria) where I live there is a special cake called 'Rhabarber Kuchen' which means roughly translated 'rheum cake'. It's very delicious imo. As it name tells, it contains [Rheum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheum_%28plant%29).

I just found a website just for this kind of cake: http://www.rhabarberkuchen.net/
Maybe you can use a translator to make something out of the recipes.

Comment: I think that's be better translated as rhubarb cake; rheum is the genus including rhubarb. And yes, rhubarb is commonly eaten in cakes and pies in the US too.

Comment: My first thought for "rheum" was something like mucus.

Answer (score -1):

Carrots, broccoli or even pumpkins they are all ideal for cakes, especially pumpkin: it gives a great taste.